# Triviality of holomorphic vector bundles over contractible Stein manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, gauge-theory

If I have correctly undrestood,it is a result of the so called Grauert-Oka principle that all holomorphic vector bundles over contractible Stein manifolds are holomorhically trivial.Does any one knows about a more direct proof?

Comment: Oka-Grauert tells you that the classification of holomorphic and topological vector bundles coincide. But being simply connected isn't sufficient for topological vector bundles to be trivial.

Comment: Yuan, I changed the question a liitle bit.

Answer (score 3):

This is a theorem which is known in classical Oka-Grauert theory , You can find the direct proof in following book page 220 and 190

Stein Manifolds and Holomorphic Mappings: The Homotopy Principle in Complex ...
 by Franc Forstneri

[Here is google book Link](https://books.google.fr/books?id=5ibv2wzZ2IQC&pg=PA301&dq=Triviality%20of%20holomorphic%20vector%20bundles%20over%20contractible%20Stein%20manifolds&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=jjPlVIGQOIX3OrTWgXA&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Triviality%20of%20holomorphic%20vector%20bundles%20over%20contractible%20Stein%20manifolds&f=false)